# ::-webkit-scrollbar doesn't work on iOS Safari?

Tags: css, scrollbar

I've created a custom scrollbar and it seems to work fine on Desktop (Chrome) and Android (Chrome) but once I try it in iOS Safari it doesn't seem to behave. The arrows are non-clickable and if I want to drag the actual scrollbar it goes the opposite way for some reason. :|

Comment: Can you provide a working example? As far as I have tried, `::-webkit-scrollbar` does work fine on iOS Safari version `10.2.1`

Comment: Can you also click on the arrow buttons and slide the slider in the correct way?

Comment: For me it seems that the arrow buttons do nothing on click in iOS and when I slide the slider to the right it slides the opposite way.

Comment: @nashcheez example of what I use: https://jsfiddle.net/cgLthppd/